# I need to split a list of lists into a list of lists of lists (check inside)

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of items like this:

```
[['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10'], ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10']]
```

and I want to turn it into this:

```
[[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']],
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```

so far I have this code:

```
for list in mylists[]:
    for items in list[]:
        items = items.split()
        print items
print mylists
```

The problem I'm getting is that

```
        print items
```

prints the list of lists how it should (how I want it to look), but then

```
print mylists
```

prints the list of lists in its original form (the original list of lists of items).

It looks like the editing of the list in place isn't holding, as if the edit is going out of scope. How can I get the edit to stay?

I know this code looks confusing so comment if you need clarification.

Comment: It's not the source of your problem, but that can't be your code.  `for list in mylists[]:` would give a `SyntaxError`.  Please always copy and paste code and transcripts exactly.

Answer (score 6):

Using `map` or comprehensions to build a new list:

```
split_mylists = [[e.split() for e in x] for x in mylists]
```

If you wish to edit in-place, you need to replace the element of the inner array:

```
mylists = [['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10'], ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10']]
for sublist in mylists:
    for i, items in enumerate(sublist):
        sublist[i] = items.split()
print mylists
```

In your code (if it was syntactically correct), you would be replacing the value of the local variable `items`, which does not reflect on the content of the (somewhat unfortunately named) list `list`.

EDIT for variable name change, and to clarify that the first snippet constructs a new list.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work :( thanks though! edit: refreshed the page, saw your addition. gimme a sec to try! edit2: the enumeration worked! thanks a bunch for your help. +1

Comment: "Didn't work" is a useless report. What did it do that you didn't expect, and what didn't it do that you did? I checked the code against your `mylists` sample above, and it does give the result you list in your OP.

Comment: The initial code is a new value - as I said, it builds a copy, does not edit in-place. However, the new value, if you reassign it to the original variable, would be the result you want. The second snippet actually edits in-place. In your code, there is no way to get the full value back, since you only calculate subvalues without storing them anywhere.

Comment: I figured setting "node = node.split()" would be what I needed to store the values, but not so apparently. I'm guessing the enumeration is what I needed to do it properly.

Comment: The point of the enumeration is that it gives you indices into the original list. Assigning to an index of a list object is *modifying* the list, which works. But assigning directly to a name, as in `node = node.split()` does not modify the *value*, it *rebinds the name*. That is, it does not cause the original list to magically turn into the result of the `split` operation, but it instead causes `node` to start being a name for the result of the `split` operation instead of the original list.

Comment: As @KarlKnechtel says - I couldn't have put it better.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are printing out the values you are generating but not storing them for further use. Since you want a list of lists of lists you should start with an empty list and add each element as you create it. Creating a second level element also involves creating third-level elements.

```
mydata = [['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10'], ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10']]

outlist = []
for lst in mydata:
    level2 = []
    for item in lst:
        level3 = item.split()
        level2.append(level3)
    outlist.append(level2)
from pprint import pprint
pprint(outlist)
```

Gives the output

```
[[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']],
 [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]]
```

Comment: @Amadan's answer is, of course, a much more concise solution to the problem.